# How to concatenate a string and the contents of a file in BASH?

Tags: bash, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate the contents (a block of code) of a file called `query.sql` in a `README.md` document, that already contains some text. However, I would also like this block of code to be preceded by a heading "Model answer".

In other words, if my `README.md` file was currently structured as

```
# Title

Some text here.
```

the new file should look like

````
# Title

Some text here.

## Model answer

```sql
Contents of query.sql
```
````

The subtitle `## Model answer` is currently not in any file, so the process should involve something like

````
cat "## Model answer\n\n```sql\n" query.sql "\n```" >> README.md
````

but `cat` only works with sets of files, not files and strings. How could I achieve the desired result in BASH?

Comment: You could make a compound statement `{ echo "Title"; cat file.sql; } > result.md`

Comment: @Mark Setchell This would remove the text already in the file `README.md`.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, so rather than making an answer, I just commented showing in broad terms, how to mix `echo` and `cat` in the hope you could work out the exact command you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can `printf` or `echo -e` the required text and then `cat` the file `query.sql` after that. You can use `&&` or `;` between the commands . If `&&` is used then the second command will be executed only if the first command was successfull. `;` is treated as a command separator

```
{ printf "## Model answer\n\n \`\`\`sql" && cat query.sql && printf "\n\`\`\`"; } >> README.md
```

or

```
{ echo -e "## Model answer\n\n '''" ; cat query.sql ; echo -e "''' /n"; } >> README.md
```

Comment: Do the backticks in the arguments to `printf` need to be escaped?

Comment: @SeSodesa Yes, yes. Sorry, I have updated the answer.

Comment: It would be simpler to use single quotes. `printf '### Model answer\n\n\n ```sql'`.

Answer (score 2):

In bash (as you have tagged it) you can do

````
cat <(echo -e '## Model answer\n\n```sql') query.sql <(echo -e '```\n') >> README.md
````

The `<()` uses process substitution; the command in parentheses is run in a subshell and its output is inserted into the larger command line. This form allows you to run without stringing lots of commands together.

If you really want avoid running commands -- for speed's sake -- you can get fancier and do this:

````
cat <(echo -e '## Model answer\n\n```sql') query.sql - <<<'```'
````

This uses *[here strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings)* instead of one command. The `-` means use standard input as an input to cat, and the ```` <<<'```' ```` at the end means send this string to standard input.

Finally the coup de grace. You can even do something like this; in your specific case it's a bit unwieldy but it demonstrates the concept:

````
$  cat /dev/fd/{4,5,6} query.sql /dev/fd/7 4<<<'### Model answer' 5<<<'' 6<<<'```sql' 7<<<'```'
### Model answer

```sql
Contents of query.sql
```
````

This means concatenate file descriptors 4, 5, and 6, query.sql, and file descriptor 7, while opening these file descriptors and sending the respective strings to them. (This doesn't require Linux [where `/dev/fd` was developed] to work, bash interprets `/dev/fd` itself and [emulates it on systems](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) that don't have it. This is why you can't do `/dev/fd/[4-6]`.) I chose these file descriptors because 0-2 are reserved for stdin, stdout, and stderr, and 10 and above are reserved for bash, and I can't count correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can read readme into a variable:

```
README=$(cat readme.md)
```

And the SQL file:

```
SQL=$(cat query.sql)
```

Combine them:

```
OUTPUT="$README

## Model answer

$SQL"
```

And echo that back to the file (double quotes needed for line breaks):

```
echo "$OUTPUT" > readme.md
```